# Why am I receiving a "call is ambigious" error when trying to user Math.Floor with an integer?

Tags: c#

I've just made a small program that uses the `Floor` method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int i;

        decimal[] t = new decimal[30];

        for(i=0; i<t.Length; i++)
        {
            t[i]=Math.Floor(i/6);
        }

        for(i=0; i<t.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(""+t[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

But it doesn't work. SharpDevelop returns this error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Math.Floor(decimal)' and 'System.Math.Floor(double)' (CS0121)

which is related to this line:

```
t[i] = Math.Floor(i/6);
```

Could someone explain me what's wrong?

Also: at first I tried writing `int[] t = new int[30];` since my program only returns integers. But it returned a second error, saying that I should use the type `decimal` instead of the type `int`. I also tried to use the type `float` and the type `double` but it didn't work either. It seems only the type `decimal` works. I would also like to know why?

Comment: The compiler has trouble deciding which overload to use since you are calling it using the result of dividing an int by an int. Which overload did you expect it to use?

Comment: You should take a look at the definition of `Math.Floor` it either takes a `double` and returns a `double` or takes a `decimal` and returns a `decimal`. In your case you pass it 2 `int`s and the compiler is confused what to do with them (treat them as `double` or `decimal`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Could someone explain me what's wrong?

The compiler is telling you exactly what's wrong - the call is ambiguous. The fact that you're trying to use the result of the call to assign into a `decimal` array is irrelevant to the compiler - it only looks at the *arguments* to the method to try to work out what method you want to call.

The type of the expression `i/6` is `int`, and that is convertible to both `double` and `decimal`, with neither conversion being "better" than the other, so the call is ambiguous. In fact, you don't really need the call at all - you're performing integer arithmetic anyway with the expression `i / 6`, which truncates towards zero - which is the equivalent to `Floor` for non-negative numbers. And you're only wanting to store integers anyway... All you need is:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // While "values" isn't a particularly descriptive name, it's better
    // than "t"
    int[] values = new int[30];

    // Limit the scope of i - declare it in the loop header
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        values[i] = i / 6;
    }

    // You don't need the index here, so use a foreach loop. Generally prefer
    // foreach over for
    foreach (int value in values)
    {
        // You don't need any string concatenation here...
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- The counter in your `for` loop is an integer.
- An integer divided by an integer results in an integer.
- Integers do not have a decimal portion, so calling `Math.Floor` is useless in the first place.
- Because of this, there is no overload `Floor(int)`.
- An integer can be implicitly converted to `double` and `decimal`, both which have this overload.
- Both are applicable and thus you get the following error.